# Class design for read-only collection properties

Tags: c#

I have an `IDictionary<string, MyEnum?>` collection that needs to be passed to a class to wrap it in a `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyEnum>` (note `MyEnum` but not `MyEnum?`).

I have come up with two designs:

1. Delay the wrapping to `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyEnum>` until property access:

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       private readonly IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MyEnum?>> _kvps;

       public MyClass(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MyEnum?>> kvps)
       {
           _kvps = kvps;
       }

       public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyEnum> Kvps
       {
           get
           {
               var filtered = from kvp in _kvps
                              where kvp.Value.HasValue
                              select kvp;
               return new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyEnum>(
                  filtered.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (MyEnum)kvp.Value);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Eagerly evaluate the collection in constructor

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       public MyClass(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MyEnum?>> kvps)
       {
           Kvps = ToReadOnly(kvps);
       }

       public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyEnum> Kvps { get; }

       private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyEnum> ToReadOnly(
           IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MyEnum?>> kvps)
       {
           var filtered = from kvp in kvps
                          where kvp.Value.HasValue
                          select kvp;
           return new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyEnum>(
              filtered.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (MyEnum)kvp.Value);
       }
   }
   ```

The [constructor design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060(v=vs.110).aspx]) section of the Framework Design Guidelines suggests that minimal work should be done in constructors so I am opting for the first approach. However, that means every call to `MyClass.Kvps` will trigger a copy of `_kvps` which is not ideal.

I would like to know which is a better approach (or are there other ways) in terms of:

- Memory efficiency (ideally only one copy of the collection is stored in `MyClass`)
- Performance (property access should be fast and should not trigger a copy of the `KeyValuePair`s)

Comment: Your two designs have different behaviours if the source dictionary is modified between construction and property access, or between consecutive property accesses. Which do you want?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I would like to property to always reflect the latest values from the source `IDictionary`. Does that mean I am only limited to my first approach?

Comment: Then yes, you'll have to do the filtering in the property accessor.

Comment: Unless you write your own `IReadOnlyDictionary` class which wraps the source. Then at least you have only the one copy of the data, but you have more filtering to do (pretty much every property access on the custom IReadOnlyDictionary).

Comment: @Blorgbeard I agree that this is probably the best way. Filtering can be minimized if the reference to the values is passed in as an `IDictionary` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the two requirements - don't copy the key value pairs and don't store two copies - you'll have to break one.

What causes us to look at this and think that there *must* be a solution is that we see `TValue` and `TValue?` and our minds want to see them as being of the same type. But they are not the same type.

It becomes clearer if you imagine that instead of `TValue` and `TValue?` that these are two different types, like an `int` and a `string`, and we want to project a collection of one to a collection of the other while filtering. For example,

```
List<string> GetStringsFromNonNegativeInts(List<int> ints)
{
    return ints.Where(i=>i>-1).Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

That's exactly the same scenario as trying to filter a set of `TValue?` to a set of `TValue`, even without the dictionary. It's just harder to see. `TValue` and `TValue?` code-blind us.

There are only two ways to do this. One is to copy each time, and the other is to keep two lists in synchronization.

Comment: Great example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** If you want the latest source values, best way is to implement your own class that implements `IReadOnlyDictionary`. Initialize this with a private field of `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, MyEnum?>`. Each call will do the lookup, and if the key exists AND `HasValue`, return the value.

Note that this implementation depends on the reference to the original values being passed in as an `IReadOnlyDictionary` to avoid having to copy values over.

---

```
public class MyReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : struct
{
    // other methods to implement here...

    public MyReadOnlyDictionary(IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue?> kvps)
    {
        _kvps = kvps;
    }

    private IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue?> _kvps;

    new public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue? val = _kvps[key];
            if (val.HasValue)
                return val.Value;
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP stated in his comments that he wants the latest source values on each call to the property, so caching won't work.

Comment: Good point. I updated my answer to reflect this. I think the comment above about implementing a new IReadOnlyDictionary implementing class is the most efficient way to go about this.

Comment: I looked at this approach too. Dealing with the enumerators seemed like a pain because you'd have to "pretend" that some of the items aren't actually in the dictionary.

Comment: @ScottHannen It depends on how you look at it. For whoever is consuming this read only dictionary, an entry with a nulled value `doesnt exist` to them, i.e., it is of no use for them and they ignore it, presumably. This new class then is just a mapping to reflect that. We don't really 'hide' anything from them, in this sense, that they wouldnt ignore anyway. It's just encapsulating the logic of ignoring nullled values.

Comment: It would have to be proven by implementing the `IReadOnlyDictionary` and testing that it behaves as expected. I understand that some values are ignored, but it would take some testing to know that everything was implemented correctly. It also doesn't eliminate the problem, it just moves it. Now consumers have the expense of repeatedly querying the inner dictionary to filter nulls.